# ScrollView stops scrolling after hidding status bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make a layout that fits to screen size when keyboard appear. This logic is working until I set theme without status bar in manifest for activity like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".signInActivity"
    android:theme="@style/TransparentNavigationBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
</activity>
```

this is my theme:

```
<style name="TransparentNavigationBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

this is my activity with example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.blabla.cd.signInActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/rarus_logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/key_hint"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/default_orange"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_button_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**If I don't set theme for that activity - everything is ok.**  How to get described behaviour without status bar?

Comment: What's your sdk version?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26